# loss of data in 2nd insert into associative array

Tags: arrays, bash

In the code below the second insert into the associative array 'originator', makes the first insert get lost. I check the 1st insert was succesfull, but when I put a second associative item into 'originators', the first item is empty, in other words, it outputs and empty string. I have no idea what could be going on.

```
declare -A originators

    while read -r line
    do
        if [ "$count" -ge "2" ]; 
        then
            inner_count=0
            #parse each line
            if [ "$debug" = "1" ] ; then  printf "%s\n" "$line" ; fi

            for word in $line
            do 

                if [ "$inner_count" = "1" ]; then tmp1="$word" ; fi
                if [ "$inner_count" = "5" ]; then tmp1="$tmp1"" ---- ""$word" ;fi 
                inner_count=$((inner_count + 1)) 
            done    
                originators=( ["$count"]="$tmp1" )
            echo "$count  ${originators["$count"]}"

        fi
    count=$((count + 1))
    done < <(batctl tg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indeed overwriting the array in this line:

```
originators=( ["$count"]="$tmp1" )
```

It should be changed to:

```
originators+=( ["$count"]="$tmp1" )
```

**This `+=` operator will append the new values into your array.**